# Web scraping: Unable to loop into div element with class to get text and URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website where i am using `div` and `class` to get the contents inside it.

i am able to get the proper data but getting error when i put it inside the loop.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
post_list = html.find_all('div', class_='eodLhs')
print(post_list)
i = 0

for values in post_list:
     url_json = {'title': values.ul.li[i].a.text, 'url': values.ul.li[i].a['href']}
     names.append(values.ul.li[i].a.text)
i = i+1
```

Output of the print statement is:
   https://gist.github.com/parikhparth23/48669444506502f11409d43b30a4250d

It throws error at this line:

```
url_json = {'title': values.ul.li[i].a.text, 'url': values.ul.li[i].a['href']}
```

I want to get the text and URL after scraping.

Comment: what's the url? Also, it looks like you really want _i_ to increment within the loop.

Comment: url is : www.divyabhaskar.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your gist I think you can just use a css selector which ensures you have child hrefs within that parent class. In your existing code the i increment should happen in the loop but isn't needed if you re-write as I describe. Use a starts with operator for the attribute value to remove the share links as I suspect you only want the original links to content

```
for i in soup.select(".eodLhs [href^='/']"):
    print({i.text:i['href']})
```